# IHP: How to validate a field with the value from an other field

Tags: haskell, ihp

I want to validate a field with the value from an other field in the Create/UpdateAction. I tried the following:

```hs
buildCo2Producer co2Producer =
  co2Producer
    |> fill @["commonSingleConsumptionFrom", "commonSingleConsumptionTo"]
    |> validateField #commonSingleConsumptionFrom (isGreaterThan 0)
    |> validateField #commonSingleConsumptionTo (isGreaterThan $ get #commonSingleConsumptionFrom co2Producer)
```

I wish #commonSingleConsumptionTo to be greater than #commonSingleConsumptionFrom, but no matter what I enter in the form, #commonSingleConsumptionFrom is always 0 in this validation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another possible solution :) Using a lambda expression `\co2Producer -> ...` to capture the piped co2Producer.

```hs
buildCo2Producer co2Producer =
  co2Producer
    |> fill @["commonSingleConsumptionFrom", "commonSingleConsumptionTo"]
    |> validateField #commonSingleConsumptionFrom (isGreaterThan 0)
    |> \co2Producer -> validateField #commonSingleConsumptionTo (isGreaterThan $ get #commonSingleConsumptionFrom co2Producer) co2Producer
```

Answer (score 0):

So my mistake was that I validated with the initial co2Producer record and not with the "filled" one that is piped through. To solve this I made a function that can take a "other field" and validate with that:

```hs
buildCo2Producer co2Producer =
  co2Producer
    |> fill @["commonSingleConsumptionFrom", "commonSingleConsumptionTo"]
    |> validateField #commonSingleConsumptionFrom (isGreaterThan 0)
    |> validateWithOtherField #commonSingleConsumptionTo isGreaterThan #commonSingleConsumptionFrom 
  where
    validateWithOtherField field validateFunction validateWithField record = validateField field (validateFunction $ get validateWithField record) record
```